# Creating a mesh on top/inside of a mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh

In the linked video at 6:40, how did the author create a face on top of the figure? How do you create a new mesh/plane on top/inside of an existing one?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kfebPwr0gx4

Also,
the faces on the mesh in the image are not flat because the edges are bent in places where there are no vertices. How do I make flat faces?
[image]
[image]

Comment: He just added a simple plane in edit mode instead of object mode so that the model stays as a single object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new object (plane), get into Edit mode, and use the *Snap* option (and *Type* > *Face*) so that the vertices of this new object stick to the other object behind. Also, enable the *Project Individual Elements* option (so that when you extrude, both the vertices stick to the other object).

[image]